# Como utilizar REST API do SharePoint Online através HTML local

Tags: sharepoint

Boa tarde,

Gostaria de saber como utilizar a API REST do Sharepoint Online através de aplicações externas, especificamente de um HTML local com JS.

Utilizando o exemplo deste artigo https://pholpar.wordpress.com/2013/05/11/accessing-office-365-sharepoint-sites-using-rest-from-a-local-html-javascript-host, recebo a seguinte msg de erro:

XMLHttpRequest cannot load https://login.microsoftonline.com/extSTS.srf. Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'null' is therefore not allowed access.

Obrigado.

Answer (score 1):

Você vai conseguir realizar consultas ao SharePoint Online dessa forma utilizando o Microsoft Graph.

Você pode escolher a plataforma que vai desenvolver com a api do Graph.

[image: Escolha da Plataforma]

Gerar uma App ID

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

E em seguida utilizar um dos códigos disponíveis pela comunidade no GitHub

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Segue: [Site Microsoft Graph](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph)
Exemplos: [Exemplos Consulta](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/graph-explorer)

[microsoftgraph](/questions/tagged/microsoftgraph)

Comment: Alterei incluindo um passo a passo para começar a utilizar a Api do Microsoft Graph. :)